# Assign foreign key automatically while bulk inserting csv file into table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, bulkinsert

I have 4 different `.CSV` files with the names `projects`, `workinOn`, `releases` and `version`. For each `.CSV` file, I a have a table with the same name as the `.CSV` files in my SQL Server database.

Before I insert the data from the `.CSV` file into the table, I bulk insert the data into a `tablename_STAGING` table. I saw someone doing it on stackoverflow when using csv files and did it too.

So now I have all files in the STAGING table. In the `.CSV` files I do not have any primary or foreign keys. I created the relationships (1:N) between the tables in SQL Server. In the normal tables I DO have a primary key column and a foreign key column (no foreign key column in `projects` as it is not needed).

I inserted the data from `projects` staging table into the real projects table. Now all projects are in there and have their unique integer id. The problem is the other tables. When I try to insert the data from `releases` STAGING into the real releases table I get a SQL error because the foreign key column `fk_projectsId` in the table releases cannot be empty. That makes sense. But how can I import all data from the STAGING table while assigning the needed foreign key for each row?

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me out.

So far I have been working with SQL Server Management Studio. I think I am going to have to do all this work in C#. Maybe I should mention that this database is going to be used by me in a C# application.

Comment: Typically, one would use an `INSERT...SELECT` query to load the taarget table, where the query joins the source staging table to related primary tables to get foreign key values. This requires an alternate key in the source data (e.g. ProjectName) to lookup the surrogate key value needed for the insert. The bottom line is there must be a way to determine how records in the different CSV files are related.

Comment: @DanGuzman that's an answer.  And more importantly, it's _the_ answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like @David and @Dan mentioned, you can proceed with INSERT INTO SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO releases (column1, column2, fk_projectsId)
SELECT rs.column1, rs.column2, p.id
FROM releases_staging rs
INNER JOIN projects p ON rs.project_name = p.name;
```

Otherwise :

```
MERGE INTO releases AS target
USING (
    SELECT r.*, p.id AS project_id
    FROM releases_staging AS r
    INNER JOIN projects AS p ON r.project_name = p.name
) AS source
ON 1 = 0 -- Always false, to force an insert
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (column1, column2, fk_projectsId)
    VALUES (source.column1, source.column2, source.project_id)
OUTPUT inserted.release_id, source.release_id
INTO releases_staging_mapping (real_release_id, staging_release_id);
```